# How to apply currency format on specific rows in R

Tags: r, format-currency

I would like to apply format Currency to row 3 and 4 of this sample data frame.
Is it possible to do it by row? I know there are functions (such as DT::formatCurrency) that can do it by column.

Thanks in advance!

Dataset:

```
A <- c(100, 7, 10000, 2000)
B <- c(150, 8, 21000, 25000)
C <- c(200, 5, 15000, 20000)

df <- data.frame(A, B, C)
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: What is the logic? Why do you choose these two rows?

Comment: You can do this, but it will convert all the columns to character `df[3:4,] <- lapply(df[3:4,], scales::dollar)`.

Comment: NelsonGon, those two rows represent total sales from current year and previous year.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, that works. Thanks! Question: which part of your code converts all columns to character?

Comment: The `scales::dollar` function converts its input to character, so by applying that to all columns you are converting them all to character (it isn't possible to convert only specific rows to character)